# Python h5py: "Unable to create file", seemingly at random

Tags: python, cluster-computing, hdf5, slurm

I am having a very strange problem with a python script that calls h5py on a slurm cluster. It almost always runs to completion just fine. However, once in about 50-100 runs it will return an "IOError: unable to create file (File accessibility: unable to open file)". Here is the offending line of code:

```
corrFile = h5py.File('/path/to/file', 'w')
```

I am not trying to create a file that already exists. The directory in which I am trying to create the file is the same for every instance of this script, whether it fails or not. The only variable which changes is the node to which the job is assigned. As far as I know, all nodes are running identical versions of all packages. I wrote this code more than a year ago, and have used it many times since without issue until recently, so I'm inclined to think it isn't strictly speaking an problem of this script being buggy.

Comment: Is it possible that a mount is missing on one of your nodes?

Comment: sounds like you should talk to your admin.

Comment: @Vorticity: Other users have not experienced any issues, so I don't think that is it.

Comment: @dbliss: Our "admin" is an overworked grad student who either doesn't know what to do or doesn't have time to do it. I'm on my own.

Comment: :(  is the offending line being run while potentially many files are being opened and closed?  maybe there's a limit to how many you're allowed to have open at once.  or, is it possible, if this is being run in parallel, that multiple instances are trying to create the same file at the same time?

Comment: Can you try writing to a different mount? If this works most of the time, but fails intermittently, I would guess that one of the nodes is configured differently. I don't know what kind of job manager you are using, but torque typically defaults to use lower numbered nodes first, so you don't see a problem until you have a lot of jobs running if the problem is on a higher numbered node.

Comment: One other thing to consider is how you are distinguishing your files from one another. Are you using PIDs or something else that might not be unique between nodes?